# HTML generating empty <td>

Tags: html, html-table

The table seems to be generating an empty `<td><td>` cell at the start of the `<th>` section. Any ideas why its doing this and how to fix it?

```html
<table>
 <th>
  <td>Vintage</td>
  <td>Product Name</td>
  <td>Size</td>
  <td>Qty</td>
  <td>Per Bottle Price</td>
  <td>Total Price</td>
 </th>
 <tr>
  <td>2005</td>
  <td>Moulin Touchais Coteaux du Layon</td>
  <td>300x100cl</td>
  <td>
   <form>
    <input type="text" value="3">
    <button>update</button>
   </form>
  </td>
  <td>£129.17</td>
  <td>£387.51</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Please explain clearly what the problem is and what you have tried to do to solve it.

Comment: `<th>` elements aren't a substitute for `<tr>` elements, they're a substitute for `<td>` elements. Your HTML is invalid.

Answer (score 2):

The th tag goes inside a row - I think this is what you're looking for:

```
<table border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>Vintage</th>
            <th>Product Name</th>
            <th>Size</th>
            <th>Qty</th>
            <th>Per Bottle Price</th>
            <th>Total Price</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2005</td>
            <td>Moulin Touchais Coteaux du Layon</td>
            <td>300x100cl</td>
            <td>
                <form>
                    <input type="text" value="3">
                    <button>update</button>
                </form>
            </td>
            <td>£129.17</td>
            <td>£387.51</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Also, you can add in the "thead" and "tbody" tags as well.

Answer (score 1):

This part is wrong:

```
        <th>
            <td>Vintage</td>
            <td>Product Name</td>
            <td>Size</td>
            <td>Qty</td>
            <td>Per Bottle Price</td>
            <td>Total Price</td>
        </th>
```

the `<th>` tag is meant to be a **header cell** (`<td>` tag is a **data cell**), not a **row** level element (`<tr>` is a table row element):

```
        <table>
        <!-- One header row -->
        <tr>
            <th>Vintage</th>
            <th>Product Name</th>
            <th>Size</th>
            ...
        </tr>

        <!-- Then one or more Data rows -->
        <tr>
            <td>2005</td>
            <td>Moulin Touchais Coteaux du Layon</td>
            <td>Size</td>
            ...
        </tr>
        </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

replace `<th>` with `<tr>` and `<td>` with `<th>`

```
<table>
            <tr>
                <th>Vintage</th>
                <th>Product Name</th>
                <th>Size</th>
                <th>Qty</th>
                <th>Per Bottle Price</th>
                <th>Total Price</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2005</td>
                <td>Moulin Touchais Coteaux du Layon</td>
                <td>300x100cl</td>
                <td>
                    <form>
                        <input type="text" value="3">
                        <button>update</button>
                    </form>
                </td>
                <td>£129.17</td>
                <td>£387.51</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
<th>
    <td>Vintage</td>
    <td>Product Name</td>
    <td>Size</td>
    <td>Qty</td>
    <td>Per Bottle Price</td>
    <td>Total Price</td>
</th>
```

with

```
<tr>
    <td>Vintage</td>
    <td>Product Name</td>
    <td>Size</td>
    <td>Qty</td>
    <td>Per Bottle Price</td>
    <td>Total Price</td>
</tr>
```